# Testing if a file exists in makefile target, and quitting if not present

Tags: makefile, gnu

Is there a way to exit with an error condition if a file does not exist? I am currently doing something like this:

```Makefile
all: foo

foo:
    test -s /opt/local/bin/gsort || echo "GNU sort does not exist! Exiting..." && exit
```

Running `make` runs the `all` target, which runs `foo`.

The expectation is that if the `test -s` conditional fails, then the `echo/exit` statements are executed.

However, even if `/usr/bin/gsort` exists, I get the result of the `echo` statement but the `exit` command does not run. This is the opposite of what I am hoping to accomplish.

What is the correct way to do something like the above?

Comment: If I try this on the command line, having the right hand side of the `||` in parenthesis, to get a sub shell, makes it work as expected. I have no idea if it's the same in a makefile. Without the parenthesis, the "exit" will be executed even if the test is positive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`exit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exit) alone returns the status of the last command executed. In this case, it returns zero, which means everything is ok.

This is, because `||` and `&&` have [equal precedence](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html), and the shell interprets the command as if it were written

```Makefile
( test ... || echo ... ) && exit
```

If you want to signal failure you must exit with a non zero value, e.g. `exit 1`.
And if you want to echo *and* exit, just put the commands in sequence separated by `;`

```Makefile
all: foo

foo:
    test -s /opt/local/bin/gsort || { echo "GNU sort does not exist! Exiting..."; exit 1; }
```

Answer (score 38):

I realize this is a bit old at this point, but you don't need to even use a subshell to test if a file exists in Make.

It also depends on how you want/expect it to run.

Using the wildcard function, like so:

```Makefile
all: foo
foo:
ifeq (,$(wildcard /opt/local/bin/gsort))
    $(error GNU Sort does not exist!)
endif
```

is one good way to do it. Note here that the ifeq clause is not indented because it is evaluated before the target itself.

If you want this to happen unconditionally for every target, you can just move it outside of a target:

```Makefile
ifeq (,$(wildcard /opt/local/bin/gsort))
$(error GNU Sort does not exist!)
endif
```

Answer (score 9):

Every command line in make runs in its own sub-shell. So running `exit` just exits that sub-shell--not the makefile as a whole. By default, `make` execution will stop if any sub-shell returns an unsuccessful exit status (by convention, 0 means success, so anything else will halt execution). The simplest method would be just to use the exit status of the `test` command:

```Makefile
all: foo

foo:
    test -s /opt/local/bin/gsort
```

Printing a diagnostic message complicates things slightly because commands like `echo` will return an exit status of 0, causing `make` to think everything is fine. To work around this, you need to run a command after it that will give the sub-shell a non-zero exit status:

```Makefile
all: foo

foo:
    test -s /opt/local/bin/gsort || { echo "GNU sort does not exist! Exiting..."; exit 1; }
```

or even just

```Makefile
all: foo

foo:
    test -s /opt/local/bin/gsort || { echo "GNU sort does not exist! Exiting..."; false; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply do:

```Makefile
all: /opt/local/bin/gsort
```

and if `/opt/local/bin/gsort` is missing, you will get a "no rule to make target `/opt/local/bin/gsort'" error message.

But if you also want some nice explanation with it do:

```Makefile
/opt/local/bin/gsort:
    echo "GNU sort does not exist! Exiting..."
    false
```

In GNU/Make if the target is not declared `.PHONEY` and doesn't have any dependencies, the rule will be invoked if a file matching that target does not exist.

The code above will trigger the `false` command only when `/opt/local/bin/gsort` does not exist, will return a non 0 value, and make will fail.

Comment: Is there a way to do this such that make continues to check for every missing file, and then return false? That way, if someone is missing a lot of files, all will show up, instead of one at a time.

Comment: @thepiercingarrow Use `make -k`, see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Testing.html

Answer (score 3):

Since you're checking whether `gsort` executable file exists, you can use `which` or `type` shell command for that, e.g.:

```Makefile
all: foo
  :

foo:
  which gsort || exit 1
  # or
  type gsort || exit 1
```

You don't need an error message, since it'll automatically print:

> /bin/sh: line 0: type: `gsort`: not found

which is obvious.

---

Alternatively use `test` or `[` (see: `help test`/`help [` for syntax), e.g.

```Makefile
test -x /opt/local/bin/gsort || { echo Error msg; exit 1; }
```

which checks if given file exists and it's executable, otherwise show the message and exit. The parenthesis are important to override the normal precedence of operators (left to right) by grouping the commands (see `Compound Commands` section in `man bash` for further info).

---

Another way is to use the rule's targets to check if the file exists and add as dependency to `all`, e.g.

```Makefile
all: /opt/local/bin/gsort
  @echo Success.

/opt/local/bin/gsort:
  @echo "GNU sort does not exist! Exiting..."
  exit 1
```

Result:

```Makefile
$ make
GNU sort does not exist! Exiting...
exit 1
make: *** [/opt/local/bin/gsort] Error 1
```